# Tilemap с rotate некорректно отображает координаты при клике

Tags: c#, unity3d

Работаю с tilemap, решил сделать немного наклонную плоскость (не изометрическую), задал свойство rotate x,y = 20.
Проверяю кликом по области значения, при rotate = 0, 0 значения корректные, как в инспекторе. При иных значениях rotate координаты выбранной клетки меняются. И не смотря на то, что ты кликаешь в то же место, показывает отсутствие tail не смотря на то, что до этого он был. Т.е получается что мы кликаем на совсем другую ячейку. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста!

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class MapManager : MonoBehaviour
{  

[SerializeField] private Tilemap tileMap;

private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector3Int gridPosition = tileMap.WorldToCell(mousePosition);

        Quaternion asd = tileMap.transform.rotation; // для получения значения rotate

        TileBase clickTale = tileMap.GetTile(gridPosition); // получаем тайл


        print("mousePosition " + mousePosition);
        print("gridPosition " + gridPosition);
        print("clickTale " + clickTale);
    }
}
}
```

Если же немного изменить код следующим образом, получаемый результат будет больше похож на желаемый, но это не отвечает на вопрос почему всё так работает:

```
Vector3Int gridPosition_new = new Vector3Int(gridPosition.x - 36, gridPosition.y + 36, 0);
TileBase clickTale = tileMap.GetTile(gridPosition_new);
```

[Координаты ячейки tilemap с rotate(20,20,0)](https://imgbb.com/1vtGL3f)

[Координаты ячейки tilemap с rotate(0,0,0)](https://ibb.co/GWtf2b8)

[Координаты ячейки в инспекторе](https://ibb.co/P1R1mSn)

Comment: А для какой цели вы весь тайлмап вращаете? Что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Цель была в том, чтобы сделать так, будто мы смотрим на tilemap под углом/наклоном (примерно как при изометрической сетке или 2.5D отображении (если в 3D работать с 2D объектами, но смотреть на них под углом)).
Я понимаю, что метод странный, но раз такая ситуация возникла, хотелось бы разобраться почему всё так работает

Comment: То есть, вместо того, чтобы просто наклонять камеру, вы решили наклонять тайлмап, что привело к таким проблемам.

Comment: Я не смог найти информацию по повороту/наклону камеры нужным мне образом в 2D проекте, чтобы ячейки отображались под нужным углом. Поэтому прибегнул к такому варианту. Но вопрос остаётся в том, что если разместить тайлы на tilemap и применить rotate, то их положение не изменится. Но при клике мышью по ячейке выдаётся позиция со смещением, и мне интересно как и почему это считается

Comment: Во-первых, у вас тайлмап и сетка находятся на канвасе, уберите их оттуда, им там явно не место, может быть все заработает. Во-вторых, камеру можно настроить [как вам угодно](https://ibb.co/09Mh0Xt) и это будет удобнее, чем вертеть тайлмап, если захочется поменять угол.

Comment: Учту ваши слова на будущее, спасибо